# Coded UI Browser Execute no effect on IE

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Try to execute a command on the browser. Succesful using Chrome, no effect using IE. Anybody any idea what might be the issue here?

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(url);
browser.ExecuteScript("var list = $('#ID')[0].selectize; list.setValue(list.search().items[0].id);");
```

Placing a breakpoint and issue the command in in the console (of IE) has the wanted effect.
Thanks in advance!
Gerard

Comment: it might be you call it too early, the browser opens, the command runs but either browser itself or DOM is just not ready yet to react to your script, I'd start with surrounding it with  document.ready and then think about a setTimeot, and if it doesnt help try to call the script from the code later (using a wait method or making a fake operation on the dom from C#)

Comment: Even placing a breakpoint, wait and continue doesn't help... Typing the command in the console during the break does have the wanted effect.